# Android <-> J2ME Bluetooth

Tags: android, java-me, bluetooth

I want to connect a generic midp2 j2me device supporting bluetooth (jsr082) to an android device, running a similar custom application I am writing.  The Android device only appears to "see" other Android bluetooth devices nearby?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you manage to succeed in your task? I have the same issue

Comment: Sorry for the delay Fernando - Richard below was the Bluetooth expert on our team, he managed to get it all working quite nicely, see below.

Comment: Yeah I reached the same solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you'll need to use reflection to hit a couple of methods (that aren't [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)) to get the same behaviour as j2me.

`createRfcommSocket(int channel)` in `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice` like

```
Class cls = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
java.lang.reflect.Method meth = cls.getMethod("createRfcommSocket",  new Class[] { Integer.TYPE});
BluetoothSocket iBluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) meth.invoke(theBTDevice,new Object[] { new Integer(channel)});
```

and

```
// getUuids() also in android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
// i.e.
Class cls = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
java.lang.reflect.Method meth = cls.getMethod("getUuids",  new Class[0]);
ParcelUuid[] uuidlist = (ParcelUuid[]) meth.invoke(theBTDevice);
```

a bit of info on the usage can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocket%28int%29):

The methods are available in earlier versions of android (I think from 2.0) but are private therefore reflection is needed (maybe they were untested and therefore hidden).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this. I used api 8 so only the

```
    BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String,UUID);
```

method is officially available.

Since Android does not allow permanent visibility I worked with the list of devices my application saved.

Here's a simplification of my code that sets Android as the server with the listening socket and the j2me phone (I used a Nokia N95) as the client to create an RFCOMM connection.

Here the Android stuff:

```
    int bytes = 0, offset = 0;
    byte[] buffer;
    BluetoothServerSocket btServerSocket = btAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("serv",myUUID);
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = btServerSocket.accept();
    OutputStream out = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = btSocket.getInputStream();
    bytes = in.read();
    buffer = new byte[bytes];
    out.write(0);
    out.flush();
    while (true)
    {
        bytes = in.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length - offset);
        offset += bytes;
        if (bytes == -1 || offset >= buffer.length)
        {
            Log.d("MyBT", "message: " + new String(buffer));
            break;
        }
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    btSocket.close();
    btServerSocket.close();
```

and here's the J2ME stuff:

```
    class ARemoteDevice extends javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice
    {
        public ARemoteDevice(String btaddr)
        {
            super(btaddr);
        }
    }

    RemoteDevice targetDevice = new ARemoteDevice("00FF00FF00FF");
    String message = "Hello my dear android device";
    UUID[] uuidSet = {new UUID("yourUUIDHERE",false)};
    Vector URLS = new Vector();
    int ENCRYPTMODE = ServiceRecord.AUTHENTICATE_ENCRYPT;
    final Object serviceSearchCompletedEvent = new Object();

    DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() 
    {
        public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {}
        public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {}
        public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++) 
            {
                String connectionURL = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ENCRYPTMODE, false);
                if (connectionURL != null) 
                {
                    URLS.addElement(connectionURL);
                }
            }
        }
        public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
            synchronized (serviceSearchCompletedEvent) {
                serviceSearchCompletedEvent.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    };

    synchronized (serviceSearchCompletedEvent) {
        discAgent.searchServices(null, uuidSet, targetDevice, listener);
        serviceSearchCompletedEvent.wait();         
    }

    if (URLS.isEmpty()) 
    {
        System.out.println("no connectionurl found");
        return;
    }

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < URLS.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println("Trying: " + (String) URLS.elementAt(i));
            try {
                sc = (StreamConnection) Connector.open((String) URLS.elementAt(i));

                in = sc.openInputStream();
                out = sc.openOutputStream();
                out.write(length);
                out.flush();
                in.read();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sc = null;
                System.out.println("Failed BT COnn");
            }
        } // TODO: handle case if all URLS fail

        int bytesSent = 0;
        int bytesToSend = 0;
        int length=message.length();
        int MTU=256;//or whatever..?
        while (true) {
            if ((length - bytesSent) > MTU) {
                bytesToSend = MTU;
            } else {
                bytesToSend = length - bytesSent;
            }
            out.write(message.getBytes(), bytesSent, bytesToSend);
            out.flush();
            bytesSent += bytesToSend;
            if (bytesSent >= length) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            in = null;
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
            sc = null;
        }
    }
```

this got my android device to accept the messages sent from j2me. I copied the important parts from my code so I'm not sure if it all works because I haven't tried executing it inline as I present it here but you should be able to fill in any mistakes I made when copy pasting this.

Good Luck!

Comment: Doesn't this solution only work for a j2me client connecting to a droid server?  The question was about droid devices seeing j2me devices - which @Richard Brough's answer above does do.

Comment: you're right in that this is only for j2me -> android server. On my own "quest" to get both directions working and reading the title assuming both directions "<->" were sought, I must have misread the part about only wanting to see j2me devices. Since I found little information on the web I thought it would fit here to post my own findings. please let me know if its distracting from the topic.